# Alpha beta pruning does not detect a candidate

Tags: pruning

My minimax graph search has considered three options at the root level of a graph.

- The first option, `A`, yields a solution with cost 10.
- The second option, `B`, was not fully investigated. It has a solution with cost 20, and the lower limit to any possible solution is 15.
- The third option, `C`, was also not fully investigated. It has a solution with cost 20, but the lower limit is only 5, so it may still be possible to find a better solution.

Alpha-beta pruning kicks in and removes option `B`, which is clearly inferior to option `A`.
This is the search tree at this point:

```
Root: 5 to 10
 |-- A: 10
 |   `-- AA: 10 [solution]
 |
 |-- B: 15 to 20 [pruned]
 |
 `-- C: 5 to 20
     |-- CA: 5 to +inf
     `-- CB: 12 to 20
          |--- CBA: 12 to 40
          `--- CBB: 20 [solution]
```

It's good that option `B` was removed.
Now, when looking more closely at option `C`, it has two children: `CA`, with cost 5 to +inf, and `CB`, with cost 12 to 20.
Considering that there is a global optimum at cost 10 already, `CB` cannot be better and should also be pruned.
However, nobody told `CB` of that. It's parent, `C`, only knows that there might be a solution with cost 5 (in branch `CA`), and (rightfully) refused to be alpha-beta pruned. It did not transmit this information to its children.

My questions are:

- Did I misunderstand alpha-beta pruning and it should actually detect `CB`?
- Which pruning algorithms support this scenario?
- Is a forward sweep in addition to backpropagation unavoidable, or can one do better?

Comment: AB pruning is "normally" depth-first, and so you don't have this problem. Of course, this has other issues.

Comment: It’s often done level by level so if we want the optimal solution for seven levels, six levels tell us a likely candidate for being optimal after seven levels, and we can try it first.

Answer (score 0):

You want a solution with the lowest cost, your opponent wants a solution with the highest cost. You examined A and it gave you a cost of 10. You examined B. You tried to find the worst move that the opponent could do on you, but any opponent move with a worst cost of "more than 10" can be ignored. There was no opponent move worse than 15, so this branch is pruned.

Then you examine C. Again, we examine moves of the opponent. If the opponent moves CA, it only costs you 5. So the opponent would hate to do that. If the opponent moves CB, you will try to get the move with the lowest cost. CBA has a cost of 12, CBB has a cost of 20, so you would move CBA. So CB has a cost of 12, which is better for your opponent than CA with a cost of 5. So when you move C, the opponent will move CB with a cost of 12. The cost of C is 12, not 5. You move A.

How A-B pruning works: You examine all your moves, assuming that your opponent will do its worst, and you want the move with the lowest worst-case cost.

You found A has a cost of 10, and you examine B. The opponent will try all its moves to find the one that is worst for you. But if a move has cost "higher than 10" then it can be ignored - you wouldn't choose move B if there is a counter move worse than 10; you would do move A.

Comment: I think you're referring to the specific case of minimax. I've mistakenly put that tag (there were few to chose from). I am sorry about the confusion, I've removed it now. The question was only about the pruning part, independent from minimax.

Comment: But alpha-beta pruning _does_solve the minimax problem, pruning branches that cannot possibly change the outcome. You can’t do pruning if you have no criterion when to prune.

Comment: Yes, the criterion is to minimize the cost, but without an opponent. It is a 'single player' environment.